# apt-get update not running before postgresql installs

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I'm using vagrant to create an instance of postgresql running on Ubuntu 10.04, using the opscode cookbooks, but for some reason `apt-get update` isn't being called before postgresql runs, so the `apt-get install postgresql` commands fail with a 404 error.  Can anyone help a chef newbie out?  I've looked through the rest of the answers, but nothing seems to work.

```
STDOUT: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql-client postgresql-client-8.4 postgresql-client-common
Suggested packages:
  postgresql-8.4 postgresql-doc-8.4
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpq5 postgresql-client postgresql-client-8.4 postgresql-client-common
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
Need to get 941kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,300kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libpq5 8.4.6-0ubuntu10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql-client-common 106ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql-client-8.4 8.4.6-0ubuntu10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main postgresql-client 8.4.6-0ubuntu10.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]STDERR: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-8.4/libpq5_8.4.6-0ubuntu10.04_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef doesn't run `apt-get update` by default, ever. You have to explicitly tell it to do so.

I'd suggest you either:

- Leverage Opscode's `apt` cookbook and call `include_recipe "apt::default"` before installing `postgresql`; or
- Adding a shell provisioner before Chef in your `Vagrantfile`:

  `config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => 'apt-get update'`

The first will work everywhere you apply the cookbook, the second will run the update everytime the Vagrant VM is provisioned, but will not force an update if you use the cookbook elsewhere.